# javascript to Jquery conversionn

Tags: jquery

Given an HTML snippet

```
<img id="progress" src="http://ajaxify.com/run/sum/progress/progress.gif" class="notWaiting"/>
```

Traditional JavaScript way, code is working:

```
function submitWord() {
    // Show progress indicator and clear existing results
    $("progress").classname="waiting";
```

But in jquery way this code below doesnt work:

```
function submitWord() {

 // Show progress indicator and clear existing results
  $("#progress").toggleClass("notWaiting waiting");
```

Also, I have tried `addClass` , and even done something like

```
$("#progress").removeClass().addClass("waiting");
```

just to make sure the default class is removed first but ,ain't helping either.

**UPDATE:** here is the JSfiddle version. 
http://jsfiddle.net/EVbh2/1/

**UPDATE 2:**
Now the problem above was that i dint refer to JQuery file itself . But still i am facing problems with code . I tried converting all the code into jquery but it aint working . 
here is a new [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pcXE3/12).

Comment: Try `.attr('class', 'waiting')`.

Comment: Well to call removeClass() you need to supply the class to remove.

Comment: Could you provide a http://jsfiddle.net example of the problem. Your jQuery code as it stands should be fine.

Comment: @MarcusRecck: No you don't.  Calling `removeClass` with no arguments removes *all* classes.

Comment: `$("#progress").classname` is ***NOT*** the "traditional JavaScript" way.  I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: Your demo has `MooTools` selected.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
$("#progress").removeClass("notWaiting").addClass("waiting");
```

This will also work, but it will wipe out all your other classes, and the only class will be "waiting":

```
$("#progress").attr("class","waiting");
```

This will also work, and is probably the simplest:

```
$("#progress").toggleClass("notWaiting waiting");
```

**UPDATE**

After looking at your fiddle, your problem is actually that you forgot to put a # in your selector of "word".  I also changed your keyup function to use the jquery equivalent.

This works:

http://jsfiddle.net/wuXL2/3/

Comment: I had generic functions defined in my orig code  that can help skip these hashes. Anyways , I have updated what the problem was . Please have a look at the new fiddle and tell me what i am doing wrong in converting it to jquery !

Comment: One thing you should definitely look into is $.ajax() - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.  This will make writing your ajax requests alot easier, and easier to read/update later.

Comment: I know about that . But how this helps mine question

Answer (score 0):

Your jsFiddle demo is *not* correct jQuery code.  In jQuery, the `$` returns a jQuery object, not a DOM element.  Because of this, you can't set properties the same way.  So you cannot do this:

```
$("word").onkeyup = function(){
};
```

You need to call the `keyup` method:

```
$('#word').keyup(function(){  // Note the '#'
});
```

Also:

```
$("results").innerHTML = "";
```

Should be:

```
$("#results").html("");  // Note the '#'
```

As for changing classes:

```
$("#progress").toggleClass("notWaiting waiting");
```

This is correct, and works 100% in jQuery.  If it doesn't work, then something else is wrong (like the incorrect jQuery code, and the fact that your jsFiddle had MooTools selected).

Fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EVbh2/3/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with chrome .  In IE it works perfectly .